# UITableView loads data too early... or too late

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, datasource

I have a UITableView that changes its data very often.  (It's just NSStrings, stored in an NSArray.)

```
Method 1> [self loadMyArray];
Method 2> [myTable reloadData];
```

Where would I put those 2 methods... so they get called EVERY time the view is displayed?

I assume some likely places would be:

```
viewWillLoad
viewDidLoad
viewWillAppear
viewDidAppear
```

But I can't seem to find the placement that is the one I need:  Each time the view appears... but BEFORE the UITableView builds itself.

If I put my 2 methods inside either "Load" delegate... it doesn't get refreshed often enough.

If I put my 2 methods inside either "Appear" delegate... I notice the data is loaded twice.  (Wasteful)

Comment: You have asked 13 questions, but not accepted even one answer. Perhaps you can go through your questions and see if there are any helpful answers that you can accept?

Comment: What do you mean by "UITableView builds itself"? Are you calling `viewWillAppear`yourself, and are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: I'm not here to "only help people if you give me bonus points".  If you don't wish to help... don't help.  I will help *ANYONE*... regardless of "do I get points for it"... or not.

Comment: *ALL* answers are helpful and welcome... except ones like "I know the answer, but I refuse to tell you because you won't give me more points".  I'm not here to deal with little children.

Comment: @Patricia you should go ahead and tick an answer on all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that 99% of the time, you should always put `[myTableView reloadData]` in `viewDidLoad`.

If you would like the UITableView to reload its data when you return to the UIView from a child view (e.g. you updated some of the data), then you need to consider what it is that you are using in the UITableView. Most of the time, I am using an NSFetchedResultsController which has its own methods to handle data updates. However there are some times when I need to update other kinds of data when the UITableView is reloaded. Here's how I deal with it: Instead of putting `[myTableView reloadData]` in `viewDidLoad`, I put it in `viewWillAppear`.

If for some reason the table is taking a long time to load and it shows a blank table before showing your data, I would look into profiling your data loading functions using Instruments, perhaps the real issue is that you need to optimize the function so that it takes less time.